# Timer in C# running in a separate thread and changing some variables

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I am programming an application in C# that reads some values from an apparatus connected to the Serial Port every 1 second. For that I want to have a timer running in a separate thread that reads the values from the Serial Port and shows the values in different labels and plot them in a chart and stores them in an collection because I need to calculate some statistics afterwards...

I managed to do that but using a public collection, which I don't like...

The problem I am facing is how can I change the collection variable each time the timer is called without using a public variable...

Thanks for your help...!

Here is part of the code:

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Interval = 1000;
    timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread task = new Thread(ReadValues);
    task.Start();
}

public void ReadValues() 
{    
    try
    {  
        temp.Add(TemperatureController.readTemperatureinKelvinInputA());
        time.Add(DateTime.Now);              
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {               
    }

    string stringTime = String.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now);

    DispTemperature(temp.Last());

    PlotAppendTemp(stringTime, temp.Last());    

    Thread.Sleep(0);
}
```

where the collection variables "temp" and "time" are public variables defined before. 
TemperatureController.readTemperatureinKelvinInputA() is a function in a library that reads the temperature from the Serial Port and return a double. DispTemperature() and PlotAppendTemp() functions display the values in the form using safe thread...

I want "time" and "temp" collections to be private variables, not public...

Comment: Post some of your code what you have tried?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show some code in order to help us understand what you are trying to achieve, and what are the challenges you are facing. Without that it will be quite difficult to help you out.

Comment: Thanks! I edited the question with some code now...

Comment: What's stopping you from making them private?

Comment: I don't know how to make them private and pass them to function where they have to be modified...I can't pass arguments to the ReadValues() function...

Comment: Assuming all the methods you showed above are in the same class, and that is the same class in which `time` and `temp` are declared, then you can simply make the declarations private - they will still be accessible by all the methods in the class.

Comment: Hi Iridium, thanks! Everything is inside the "public partial class Form1 : Form". Do you mean that I can create a private variable that will be accessible by all the elements of the form, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using variables as public is not a good idea, this is why you don't like it anyway. I suppose that you have the `time` and `temp` collections as `public` because they are used by another part of code too. If they are not used anywhere **outside the specific class**, then you could just turn them `private` as Iridium suggests.

In the case that these collections are used in other parts of the system, I would suggest to identify all the parts of the system which use the specific collections. Then you would have to decrease those interactions to a minimum, resulting in an overall restructuring of your code.

**Nobody can give a satisfying answer if the parts of your code using those collections are not identified.**

Hope I helped!

Comment: Thanks ! I think that is also what Iridium suggest...I said it wrong. I meant I had to create a private variable accessible by every element inside the form class. Is that a OK in terms of encapsulation?

Comment: Yes, it is the same Iridium suggest (give him credit points). I suppose turning the collections private is OK. These decisions are subjective. I would use a service layer with no user interface to gather the data from the "sensors", and then my forms would call the service to get the data. This way the forms would only be used for display purposes, but this is a personal opinion. If you want to keep thing simple, you could turn the collections private inside form.

Answer (score 0):

You should not spawn a new thread on each timer-tick. Better remove the timer anyway and use a Thread or BackgroundWorker that sleeps a bit after each cycle. Within a cycle of the thread read from your data from the serial port and then add them to your collection using lock() pattern. Use lock() everywhere else where you access the same collection.

And I suggest using a dictionary whereas the key is the DateTime and the value the data from the serial port. Better than using two collections.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about that also....I wonder what is better to do this or use instead a System.Threading.Timer...

Comment: You can use both, but if you are using Timer, then you don't need to spawn a new child thread (as you did). The timer is already running in an own thread. But I would prefer using a thread instead of a timer.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the timer I am using is the  System.Windows.Forms.Timer that runs in the same thread than UI, the one you are saying is the System.Threading.Timer, right?

Comment: Correct, but then it's even more important to use a thread or the System.Threading.Timer. This is because the operation that reads from the serial port might take longer than expected and your desired timer interval won't hold. Then the message queue adds up and the UI is not responsive anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Why not wrap your collection (as others have said, a generic Dictionary would be ideal) holding your data in a nice class that presents public methods to add a (datetime, temperature) pair to the collection in a thread safe manner (as others have said, use the lock() statement).

Then run your timer in a second thread that is a simple loop. So it reads the data from the serial port, adds the data to the collection (via those public, threadsafe methods), then sleeps for 1 second before repeating.